# Why Can't I access src/test/resources in Junit test run with Maven?

Tags: java, junit4, mockito

I am having a problems running the following code:

```
configService.setMainConfig("src/test/resources/MainConfig.xml");
```

From within a Junit @Before method.

Is this the way Maven builds out its target folder?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Access `MainConfig.xml` directly. The `src/test/resources` directory contents are placed in the root of your CLASSPATH.

More precisely: contents of `src/test/resources` are copied into `target/test-classes`, so if you have the following project structure:

```
.
└── src
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── foo
        │       └── C.java
        └── resources
            ├── a.xml
            └── foo
                └── b.xml
```

It will result with the following test CLASSPATH contents:

- `/foo/C.class`
- `/a.xml`
- `/foo/b.xml`

To actually access the files from Java source, use 
`getClass().getResource("/MainConfig.xml").getFile()`.

Comment: Thanks for this consise answer. You are indeed correct that the file can be seen under /target/test-classes. I still cannot ref it from my code however. Have tried all sorts of combinations: 'configService.setMainConfig("MainConfig.xml"); '
'configService.setMainConfig("target/test-classes/MainConfig.xml"); '

configService.setMainConfig("classpath:MainConfig.xml"); etc etc

Comment: Try `getClass().getResource("/MainConfig.xml").getFile()`

Comment: If you are using Tycho and eclipse-plugin as packaging type, don't forget to aadd src/test/resources in build.properties file.

Comment: Thank you, but i run my junit in jenkins its failing, for some reason the files from src/test/resource is getting copied to /target/classes instead of /target/test-classes

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem today and I have found some solutions.

First, here is my file structure:

```
.
└── src
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       │   └── mypackage
│       │       └── MyClassTest.java
│       └── resources
│           └── image.jpg
└── target
    └── test-classes
            ├── image.jpg
            └── mypackage
                └── MyClassTest.class
```

**What is not working:** (Java 11 synthax)

```
var imgFile = new File("image.jpg"); // I was expecting that Junit could find the file.
var absPath = file.getAbsolutePath(); // /home/<user>/../<project-root>/image.jpg
var anyFileUnderThisPath = file.exists(); // false
```

What we can notice is that the *absolute path* does not point at all on my image! But if I had an image under at the project-root, then it would have worked.

**Solution 1: Paths** (introduced in Java 7)

```
var relPath = Paths.get("src", "test", "resources", "image.jpg"); // src/test/resources/image.jgp
var absPath = relPath.toFile().getAbsolutePath(); // /home/<user>/../<project-root>/src/test/resources/image.jpg
var anyFileUnderThisPath = new File(absPath).exists(); // true
```

As we can see, it points on the right file.

**Solution 2: ClassLoader**

```
var classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
var url = classLoader.getResource("image.jpg"); // file:/home/<user>/../<project-root>/target/test-classes/image.jpg
var file = new File(url.getFile()); // /home/<user>/../<project-root>/target/test-classes/image.jpg
var anyFileUnderThisPath = file.exists(); // true
```

Note that now the file is searched under the target directory! and it works.

**Solution 3: File** (Adaptation of the non-working example)

```
var absPath = new File("src/test/resources/image.jpg").getAbsolutePath();
var var anyFileUnderThisPath = new File(absPath).exists(); // true
```

Which works also after taking the absolute path and putting `src/test/resources/` as prefix.

**Summary**

All three solutions works but having to put `src/test/resources/` is, in my own opinion not elegant, and this is why I would prefer the 2nd solution (`ClassLoader`).

Sources:

- [Read file and resource in junit test](https://howtoprogram.xyz/2017/01/17/read-file-and-resource-in-junit-test/)
- [Java read a file from resources folder](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/)

Answer (score 3):

I guess `setMainConfig` expects the path of a resource, that it will load using the ClassLoader, and not a relative file path. It would help if you linked to the javadoc of this mysterious `configService.setMainConfig` method.

If my guess is correct, then the path should just be MainConfig.xml. Mave copies the contents of `src/test/resources` to the `target/test-classes` (IIRC) folder. And this test-classes folder is in the classpath of the unit tests.

Comment: Thanks for this. your logic is correct(see comment above) but unfortunatley I still cannot get this to work