# Cant access a file from /resource-folder in a JUnit-Test

Tags: java, junit

1. Summarize the problem:

I'm testing a Spring-Rest/MVC-Api (without Spring-Boot) with JUnit 5.
I have a class CatRepositoryBackUpRepo, i read and write a file there that i link with
`private File datei = new File("Cats.json");`. This file is in src/main/resource. This works fine when i run the program. I checked it with the println-Logging-Text.
When i want to test this read-method in a Junit-test-Class (link at the end), it didn't find the file, and throw a file not found exception.

2. Describe what you’ve tried:

I created a /src/test/resource-folder and place the same file there, but didnt worked. Then i used the test-class to write such a file and it was placed on the same level as the /src-Folder and the pom.xml, on the project-path. It seems that the property for the resource-path when running the testclass is the problem, but i dont know how to fix it, how to tell the class-under-test the correct property.
I run the test-cases with Junit in a IntelliJ Ultimate Edit., the working directory of the run-configuration for Junit is set to `$MODULE_WORKING_DIR$`.

3. Add some code

This is the class under test, with the method under test `readCats()`
https://github.com/IngmarEckhardt/RestControl/blob/master/src/main/java/de/cats/restcat/service/CatRepositoryBackupRepo.java

And this is the test-class, the only method that doesnt worked is  `readCats_withHDDready_shouldReturnArrayList()`

https://github.com/IngmarEckhardt/RestControl/blob/master/src/test/java/de/cats/restcat/service/CatRepositoryBackupRepoTest.java

Comment: Hey welcome on SO. Keep in mind to use the search function first before asking questions. Searching for your problems I found some sites that might help you and understand the problem better and your suggested solution since it is not optimal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40710420/reading-a-resource-file-in-junit-test , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673651/how-to-get-the-path-of-src-test-resources-directory-in-junit , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613359/why-cant-i-access-src-test-resources-in-junit-test-run-with-maven

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I solved the problem by myself, but i will share the solution if anybody search for it.

The problem was, that the spring-mvc-Framework uses a Classloader to get resources from the classpath, and this classloader is behind the scene invoked with the call for `new File("Cats.json")`.

But obviously this doesn't work out with the test-class. I call the Classloader now explicit with

```java
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File datei = new File(classLoader.getResource("Cats.json").getFile());
```

instead of just using

```java
File datei = new File("Cats.json");
```

This solved my problem.